# Get custom size of thumbnails

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

This how I am currently retrieving slides:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'post_type' => 'slide'
    );
    $slides = new WP_Query( $args );    
    ?>

    <?php if($slides->post_count > 0) :?>
    <div class="slideshow">         
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php $i = 1; while ($slides->have_posts()) : $slides->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                //Get slide options         
                $slide_background_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ttrust_slide_background_image", true), 'full');          
                $slide_background_img = $slide_background_img[0];

                $s_styles = "";
                $s_class = "";
                if($slide_background_img){
                    $s_styles .= "background-image: url(".$slide_background_img.");";                           
                }       
                ?>                  

                <li id="slide<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php post_class($s_class); ?> style="<?php echo $s_styles;?>">
```

And in functions.php I have setted this thumb size:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');  
add_image_size( 'vip-thumb', 1024, 9999 ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
```

If in the earlier code, i change:

```
$slide_background_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ttrust_slide_background_image", true), 'full');
```

To

```
$slide_background_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ttrust_slide_background_image", true), 'vip-thumb');
```

or

```
$slide_background_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ttrust_slide_background_image", true), 'vip-thumb', true);
```

I don't get a resized thumb, just the original image

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to use `set_post_thumbnail_size();` for thumbnails? And then the `the_post_thumbnail('vip-thumb' );`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size